# Distributing dataframe column headers to a dataframe row and stacking column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transpose

How do I perform the following transformation to a Pandas dataframe? Convert column headers to a column and stack the values from each column into a single column. An image is attached to help clarify.

[image: Goal description]

Comment: check - https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html

Comment: Please include any relevant information [as text directly into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), do not link or embed external images of source code or data. Images make it difficult to efficiently assist you as they cannot be copied and offer poor usability as they cannot be searched. See: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15497888)

Comment: Please note to take an extra sorting of date sequence to make the exact result you want, if you use melt() for your solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df.melt('date', var_name='stock', value_name='quantity')
```

Output:

```
   date stock  quantity
0  2015   ABT         5
1  2016   ABT         6
2  2015  ABBV        32
3  2016  ABBV        14
```

Given df,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':[2015, 2016],
                  'ABT':[5,6],
                  'ABBV':[32, 14]})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df = df.set_index('date').stack().reset_index()
df.columns = ['date', 'stock', 'quantity']
```

Result:

```
print(df)


   date stock  quantity
0  2015   ABT         5
1  2015  ABBV        32
2  2016   ABT         6
3  2016  ABBV        14
```